# Argparse: How to accept any number of optional arguments (starting with `-` or `--`)

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to create a command line tool (let's call it 'X') that wraps another tool (let's call it 'Y').

I handle some cases specially, and add some options of myself, but I want to redirect whatever I don't want to handle to the tool Y.

So far I managed to redirect the arguments that don't come with dashes, for example `X Y option1 option2 option3` will just call `Y option1 option2 option3`. I did this by adding a subparser `Y` and an argument `any` to it

Here's the code (x.py):

```
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(dest="parser_name")

y_subparser = subparsers.add_parser('y')
y_options = y_subparser.add_argument('any', nargs='*')
```

Then in my handler code, i do this:

```
args = main_parser.parse_args()
if args.parser_name == 'y':
    command_string = ' '.join(['y'] + sys.argv[2:])
    os.system(command_string)
```

When I call `python x.py y asdf zxcv qwer` it works.

When I call `python x.py y asdf zxcv qwer -option` I get the error `x.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -option`

I realize that if stuff just gets too complicated with argparse i can always fall back to using `sys.argv`, but if you know this to be doable, please share.

I've also been looking through the argparse code, which is a little dense, and where it seems that `ArgumentParser._parse_known_args` does everything (300 lines). But before I go deeper, I thought maybe someone knows how to do this - if not, i'll post my discoveries here if someone else has the same problem.

Comment: `'--'` forces the parser to treat anything that follows as argument, e.g. `'python x.py y asdf zxcv qwer -- -option'`

Comment: I think instead of using 'any' to hold undefined argument options, you can add _args, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()_ and use the 'unknown' variable as you would use the 'any' in your code.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the doc of argparse, you can use [`argparse.REMAINDER`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#intermixed-parsing) :

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> parser.add_argument('command')
>>> parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
>>> print(parser.parse_args('--foo B cmd --arg1 XX ZZ'.split()))
Namespace(args=['--arg1', 'XX', 'ZZ'], command='cmd', foo='B')
```

This work even with dashed in the subcommand arguments

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> parser.add_argument('command')
>>> parser.add_argument('args', nargs=argparse.REMAINDER)
>>> print(parser.parse_args('--foo B cmd --arg1 XX ZZ --foobar'.split()))
Namespace(args=['--arg1', 'XX', 'ZZ', '--foobar'], command='cmd', foo='B')
```

Comment: The mentioned documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#intermixed-parsing)

Answer (score -1):

I found this workaround:

Instead of using simply `main_parser.parse_args()` I do this

```
def remove_dashes_from_args(args):
    return [arg.replace('-','#$%#$') for arg in args]

main_parser.parse_args(replace_dashes_from_args(sys.argv[1:]))
```

And then when calling the `Y` command I didn't have to change anything, because I was already using sys.argv:

```
if arg.parser_name == 'y':
    os.system(' '.join(['y'] + sys.argv[2:]))
```